# what is the best python method for encryption

Tags: encryption, pgp

I retrieved the PGP key from the public key server ,Now need help in getting a python method for encryption which can accept this PGP public key .

As i know PGP/Gnupg.py module do not allow me to use encryption/decryption function separately without generating the key.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the easiest approach is use [GPGME](http://www.gnupg.org/gpgme.html), which is basically GnuPG wrapped up in a convenient library form (thus the name, GPGME = GnuPG Made Easy). There is a Python wrapper for GPGME named [Pyme](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/) which will let you do things like import keys, encrypt messages using them, etc, all using the standard PGP formats. There is some basic [Pyme documentation](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/doc/pyme/index.html) online, along with the promise of more complicated examples being included in the source distribution.